# Search NSString for unknown string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

In my iOS app I get the complete HTML of the website as an `NSString`. Further down along the line I need an `NSString *pageTitle` in the code. So, ideally, what I would like to do is search the `NSString` for `<title>Title of page</title>`.

I imagine what I need to do, is look for `<title>` then take the part after it up until `</title>`. However, I don't know how to do this properly. Any ideas?

This is what I have so far:

```
NSString *string = @"<html><head><title>Title of page</title></head><body></body></html>";
if ([string rangeOfString:@"<title>"].location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"string does not contain a title");
} else {
    NSLog(@"string contains a title!");
}
```

Comment: You could start by reading the spec for NSString.

Comment: @HotLicks some people just want somebody to work for them for free

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you need to do something like this [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/index.html) is the tool to use.

```
NSString *string = @"<html><head><title>Title of page</title></head><body></body></html>";

// Set up convenience variables for the start and end tag;
NSString *startTag = @"<title>";
NSString *endTag = @"</title>";

// Declare a string variable which will eventually contain the title
NSString *title;

// Create a scanner with the string you want to scan.
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];

// Scan up to the <title>, throw away the result.
[scanner scanUpToString:startTag intoString:nil];

// Scan <title>, throw away the result.
[scanner scanString:startTag intoString:nil];

// Scan up to the </title> tag, put the characters into `title`
[scanner scanUpToString:endTag intoString:&title];

// Just to show that I'm not lying, print out the scanned title to the console.
NSLog(@"Title is: %@", title);
```

Comment: Why should he use this approach when the substring scheme is simpler and shorter and easier to understand?

Comment: Because substring searches, are just that - substring searches. NSScanner is a class designed to do just this: scan a string in one pass and extract things from them. It's the right tool for the job.

Comment: But why use a complex and hard to understand mechanism when a simple one works just as well??

Comment: It's not complex at all; it's just walking through strings and pulling bits out. It seems complex because it's unfamiliar, but once you get used to it they are quite simple. And it's usually a good idea to point someone to the right way to do something, even if it is a bit more complicated.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to explain how to do a job using simple and easy-to-understand tools first.  One can get into the fancy stuff later.  Much of the confusion that newbies have with computing is due to folks pushing complex answers for simple questions.

Comment: That's assuming all newbies want to know how to do something the simplest way. I didn't when I was a newbie, and I learned plenty of interesting approaches to problems from answers that didn't give the obvious "beginner tutorial" answer. At the very least, the OP, and anyone else reading this is now aware that there is a class called `NSScanner` that does these things.

Comment: Yep, and you've taught him that, rather than consulting the documentation he has at hand and trying to understand how to deal with the problem, he should instead ask on SO for some esoteric package he doesn't understand but can apply "cookbook" fashion.  Good going!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to get the title:

```
NSRange searchFromRange = [string rangeOfString:@"<title>"];
NSRange searchToRange = [string rangeOfString:@"</title>"];
NSString *title= [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(searchFromRange.location+searchFromRange.length, searchToRange.location-searchFromRange.location-searchFromRange.length)];
NSLog(@"title=%@",title);
```

Comment: Where `substring` would be the title?